# Proving matrix transposition equals to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

I am solving some exercises, one of which I need to prove the following:

Suppose $A\epsilon M_n(\Re)$

if $A^T.A = 0$ then $A=0$

The solution I have come up with is the following:

Let $B = A = 0$ (1), show that $A^T.B = 0$

$A^T.B$ = $\sum_{ k \mathop =1}^na^T_{ij}b_{i,j}$

By (1) $b_{i,j} = 0$ so summation = 0, thus $A^T.B = 0$.

Is this the correct way to prove it?

Comment: In statement (1) are you asserting that $ A_{ij} = 0$ for all $ i, j $? How do you know that?

Comment: I'm assuming it. Can't I do that?

Comment: What's the difference between $ A_{ij} $ and $ a_{ij} $? This notation should be explained before using it, and the notation should be consistent.

Comment: I probably should have left it as $A$. I edited my answer is that any better?

Comment: Your goal is to prove that $ A $ is the zero matrix, so we can't assume at the beginning that $ A $ is zero. That is a circular argument.

Comment: Right, any hint on how I can start solving it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the special case where $ A $ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix? This might shed some light on the problem. You can write $ A^T A $ explicitly in terms of the entries of $ A $.

Comment: I see that if it is a $2x2$ matrix then only the antidiagonal elements are swapped, but I can't see how that helps me

Comment: In the case where $ A= \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$, I think it will be helpful to write out the entries of $ A^T A $ explicitly.

Comment: I've written down $A^T A$ explicitly, it's getting me nowhere.

Comment: But can you tell me what you got for the entries of $A^T A$?  What's the upper left entry of $A^T A$?

Comment: Use the inner product: $({A^T}Af,f)=(Af,Af)=0$ implies that $Af=0$ for all $f$. Hence $A$ must vanish.

Comment: @littleO The upper left is $a_{1,1}.a_{1,1} + a_{2,1}.a_{2,1} $

Comment: Yes, the upper left entry is $a_{11}^2 + a_{21}^2$.  So if $A^T A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then we know that $a_{11}^2 + a_{21}^2 = 0$.  But this means that $a_{11}$ and $a_{21}$ are both zero, otherwise $a_{11}^2 + a_{21}^2$ would have to be positive.  So we see that $a_{11}$ and $a_{21}$ are both zero.  That's definitely a good step towards showing that $A = 0$.

Comment: @Urgje I'm sorry I don't know what the inner product is

Comment: @littleO Well that's half of the matrix shown to be 0.. but then there's also another half and also this is just for a matrix that's 2x2

Comment: Yes, we've managed to show that half of the matrix is $0$, and that is a great step forward.  When we see how to handle the $2 \times 2$ case, the same approach will work for the $n \times n$ case.  I think you can figure out how to show the other half of the matrix is also zero.

Comment: Right.. I've shown that the other matrix is zero using the lower right entry. How would I generalize this?

Comment: That is a pitie since now you have to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The $(i,i)$ entry of $A^T A$ is

$$ (A^T A)_{i,i} = \sum_{k=1}^n (A^T)_{i,k} A_{k, i} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{k,i} A_{k,i} = \sum_{k=1}^n (A_{k,i})^2. $$

Comment: So that means that for any k,i $A_{k,i}$ must be zero?

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: Is that all there is to the proof?

Comment: What more is needed?

Comment: I was asking, not insinuating anything